# Authentication recipe

Tags: angular, ngxs

I came across this

https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/recipes/authentication

I'm questionning the use of the authService inside the AuthState class.

Wouldn't it be better if the Login component was responsible to authenticate with the authService and THEN dispatch the login action (to set token + auth flags)?

If not, then should the AuthState class handle failed logins and react with 
 (for example) a patchState ({loginFailed: true, errorCode: 'WrongPassword'}) .. ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you adopt the pattern of changing state via action dispatch and using services as part of action method, there's no reason to do auth differently.  In a current app I'm building I have the model:

```
export interface AuthStateModel {
  user: User | undefined;
  token: JWT | undefined;
  authenticated: boolean;
  responseStatus: number | undefined;
}
```

a login action of

```
export class Login {
  static type = '[auth] Login';
  constructor(public username: string, public password: string) {}
}
```

and an action method of

```
  @Action(Login)
  login(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: Login) {
    //
    // Use the auth service to authenticate the user
    //
    return this.authService.login(action.username, action.password).pipe(
      tap( (ar: AuthResponse) => {
        ctx.patchState({
          user: ar.user,
          token: ar.token,
          authenticated: true,
          responseStatus: undefined});
        }),
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse, loginResult: Observable<AuthResponse>) => {
        return of(ctx.patchState( {responseStatus: err.status} ));
      }));
  }
```

The login form has an *error* div that shows a reasonable message if the responseStatus isn't 200-ish using the async pipe and the component's onSubmit navigates to the root page of the app if the login works:

```
  onSubmit() {
    const username = this.loginFormGroup.value.username;
    const password = this.loginFormGroup.value.password;
    this.manageSubscription(this.store.dispatch(new Login(username, password)).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.authState$)).subscribe( ([authStateModel]) => {
        if (authStateModel.auth.authenticated) {
          this.manageSubscription(
            this.store.dispatch(new GetClient(1)).subscribe((_x: void) => {
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }));
        }
    }));
  }
```

Obviously you can refactor the service call to inside of the login component's onSubmit method, but I don't see how that would be an advantage.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time! I'd thought about adding the responseStatus to the state but I was questionning the idea since a responseStatus is more a "one-time" response to an action than a piece of data you want to maintain. Maybe I don't totally get the pattern. I'll read a little more about it I guess!